# Scrollable window in WXpython

Tags: wxpython

I need a scrollable frame window and trying to use ScrollWindow() method, what should be the parameters for this method docstring to make the frame completely scrollable..

```
ScrollWindow(self, int dx, int dy, Rect rect=None)

Physically scrolls the pixels in the window and move child 
 windows
accordingly.  Use this function to optimise your scrolling
implementations, to minimise the area that must be redrawn. 
 Note that
it is rarely required to call this function from a user program.
```

import wx

```
class Example(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        super(Example, self).__init__(parent, title=title, 
            size=(300, 250))

        self.InitUI()
        self.Centre()
        self.Show()
        self.ScrollWindow()


    def InitUI(self):

        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        hbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        fgs = wx.FlexGridSizer(3, 2, 9, 25)

        title = wx.StaticText(panel, label="Title")
        author = wx.StaticText(panel, label="Author")
        review = wx.StaticText(panel, label="Review")

        tc1 = wx.TextCtrl(panel)
        tc2 = wx.TextCtrl(panel)
        tc3 = wx.TextCtrl(panel, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)

        fgs.AddMany([(title), (tc1, 1, wx.EXPAND), (author), 
            (tc2, 1, wx.EXPAND), (review, 1, wx.EXPAND), (tc3, 1, wx.EXPAND)])

        fgs.AddGrowableRow(2, 1)
        fgs.AddGrowableCol(1, 1)

        hbox.Add(fgs, proportion=1, flag=wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, border=15)
        panel.SetSizer(hbox)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = wx.App(False)
    Example(None, title='Review')
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

ScrollWindow doesn't add a scrolling window, its for making a window scroll which is what it states in your post.

> Physically scrolls the pixels in the window and move child windows accordingly.

There is ScrolledWindow or ScrolledPanel have a look at them in the wxpython demo